# PHP array: integer index vs string index

Tags: php, arrays, memory, integer, associative-array

Is there any difference between **integer index** and **string index** of PHP arrays (except of course the fact that the latter is called `associative array`)?

So for example, what are the differences between the following two arrays:

```
$intIndex[5] = "Hello";
$intIndex[6] = "World";
$intIndex[7] = "!";
```

And

```
$strIndex['5'] = "Hello";
$strIndex['6'] = "World";
$strIndex['7'] = "!";
```

In the first case, what happens to `$intIndex[0]` to `$intIndex[4]`?

Comment: It gives you an `Undefined index 0/4` PHP warning.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Could you please clarify why it gives that error? I thought in PHP, there is no need for variable declaration.

Comment: Well you don't have an entry in your array with key `0` or `4`. It's an undefined index in this array. So if you use `$intIndex[0]` you will run into an `Undefined index` PHP warning.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Okay, so is that memory unallocated? I mean, even if I use $arr[1000] directly, the first 999 indices are not wasted?

Comment: I mean first 1000 (0-999) indices.

Comment: Yes that memory is unallocated. Because those indeces don't exist. But you allocate it "automatically" as soon as you give the array index a value. So `$intIndex[0] = 'foo';` will allocate memory for this specific index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/array) (emphasis mine):

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any
>   type.
>
> Additionally the following key **casts will occur**:
>
> - **Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type**. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other
>     hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.
> - Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under
>
>     8.
> - [...]

That's not related with the fact that PHP arrays are sparse.

You can verify all this with [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump).