# How can I shorten my code with isset values

Tags: php, unique-values

Im am so lost. Can anyone explain how i can shorten this code. I have hundreds of these! I submit a form with input value. Whenever i dont fill in a value, i get an error. So i made these isset blocks to prevent returning the error. But i seem so unefficient! Please help...thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['input74'])){
$value74 = $_POST['input74'];
}else{
$value74 = "";#default value
}

if(isset($_POST['input75'])){
$value75 = $_POST['input75'];
}else{
$value75 = "";#default value
}

if(isset($_POST['input76'])){
$value76 = $_POST['input76'];
}else{
$value76 = "";#default value
```

Comment: One option: `$value74 = isset($_POST['input74']) ? $_POST['input74'] : "";`. You could loop and replace the number with a variable.

Comment: If you find yourself numbering inputs like this, then you should probably use an array instead.... and then you can loop over it in PHP rather than explicitly having to name each element

Comment: Use the ternary operators like @FirstOne suggested to get the variable assignments on a single line. However, you really should follow the advice from Mark Baker

Comment: Please update your question with a sample from your form. It will be easier to provide an alternative or an answer to your question

Comment: Also, it would help to know how are you going to use the variables from the `$_POST`

Comment: A brief synopsis of the bigger picture of what you are trying to do here would be helpful. What you are doing in the code in your question really seems more indicative of a design error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has support for arrays in forms. You can name your form fields with indexes, e.g. `<input type="text" name="input[74]" ... />`. Then in PHP, you can access those with a `for` or `foreach` loop, because they will be available as an array (i.e. you will have `$_POST["input"][74]`). You could thus write something like:

```
$values = $_POST["input"];
for ($i = 0; $i < MAX_INPUTS; $i++) {
  if (!isset($values[$i])) {
    $values[$i] = "";  // default value
  }
}
```

If for some reason you can't change the HTML side, you could still use a loop to dynamically create the field names and copy the data to an array on the PHP side, something like:

```
$value = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < MAX_INPUTS; $i++) {
  $name = sprintf("input%d", $i);
  if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
    $value[$i] = $_POST[$name];
  } else {
    $value[$i] = "";  // default
  }
}
```

In both proposed solutions, you only have some lines of code instead of dozens of repetitions of almost the same lines. In both examples, I assumes that your fields start with `input0` and that there is a total of `MAX_INPUTS` fields. If not all fields exist (e.g. you only have input1, intput2, input74 and input75), you can create an array with the fields numbers:

```
$field_list = array(1,2,74,75);
```

And then use that to check your data (here the example with arrays in HTML field names):

```
$values = $_POST["input"];
foreach ($field_list as $num) {
  if (!isset($values[$num])) {
    $values[$num] = "";  // default value
  }
}
```

Comment: your example won't work, as using the name field will turn all of the contents into strings. `name="input[74]"` will actually come out as `$_POST["input"]["74"]`, NOT `$_POST["input"][74]`. not only that, `HTML` actually holds the support for arrays in forms creating a querystring that php can decipher. But so can Java or JavaScript

Comment: Sorry @iam-decoder:  That is not correct.  Integer keys will be integer keys in PHP.

Comment: Indeed, I just tried... although string indexes wouldn't hurt anyway because of dynamic typing.

Comment: weird, does this differ on IIS servers? because the string casting was the answer to a question here on SO not too long ago

Comment: it is clearly stated in the PHP manual that any string index to an array that is a valid integer will be used as such... see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26119646/1931985 -- @iam-decoder, do you have a link to the IIS-related answer for string casting? I'm curious to see more about this...

Comment: is there a way to view all the posts I commented on? I believe I didn't submit an answer on that post

Comment: @iam-decoder in your profile go to the activity tab, go to "all actions" tab and select "comments". it'll appear there unless the comment or answer has been deleted

Comment: @Ale here it is, i see now that It's because it was converted to a JSON object rather than an array which caused my confusion: [Create multidimensional array only with html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657080/create-multidimensional-array-only-with-html#comment55089283_33657080)

Answer (score 1):

you could wrap the `isset` in a function like this

```
function myIsset(&$variable, $default = "")
{
    if(isset($variable))
    {
        return $variable;
    }
    else
    {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

then you just call it like `$value74 = myIsset($_POST['input74']);`

the second argument defaults to an empty string so if you want to set the default value you can supply it or change what the default is in the function header if they will just all be the same. bellow is a screen shot showing the code working

[image: test]

while yes you are still going to have one line per `$_POST` at least you exchnge 5 lines of code with 1 line of code and the function above. you can possibly reduce this to a loop like how i explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33513954/1028804) however without seeing the form and confirming any pattern i can't give any code examples for that since what you have shown could just be a coincidence

Comment: Change it to `myIsset(&$variable, ...`

Comment: @AbraCadaver that is incorrect. i tried it with not just the OP's `$_POST` variables but also this line of code `$hello = "dood"; var_dump(myIsset($hello));`. commenting out the `$hello` line and it shows that it will return whatever i specified `$default` to when commented out and when it isn't it'll return the exact same value  passed. adding `&$variable` gave the exact same resaults

Comment: @Memor-X turn on error reporting and you will see why your code is incorrect. Pass the variable by reference instead, to avoid the undefined variable warning, which is really the point of using isset in the first place. There is a version of this function in the comments section of the isset manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#95557

Comment: @rjdown ahhh that might be why. i tend to have those turned off

Comment: @downvoter if your downvote was about how i originally had `$variable` instead of `&$variable` then you can remove your downvote as that has been fixed. otherwise please explain what is wrong

Comment: Not my downvote, though I did explain what was wrong, and I see you fixed it. Have an upvote :) There was another comment above mine that has since been deleted, saying that the variable would always be set in the function... it was wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7 has a new operator to address this specific situation: the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) (??) replaces this:

```
$foo = isset($foo) ? $foo : $bar
```

With this:

```
$foo = $foo ?? $bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ternaries to shorten the code:

```
$value74 = isset($_POST['input74']) ? $_POST['input74'] : 'Default value';
$value75 = isset($_POST['input75']) ? $_POST['input75'] : 'Default value';
$value76 = isset($_POST['input76']) ? $_POST['input76'] : 'Default value';
```

Or you could loop through $_POST array as well, but some filtering/validation must be done. Quick idea:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $i = 0;
    $arr = array();
    foreach($_POST as $input) {
        $arr[$i] = $input;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

`$arr` would then produce an array like

```
Array
(
    [74] => 'value74'
    [75] => 'value75'
    [76] => 'value76'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_merge`.

You would set up your default array with all the default input values provided.

```
$aryDefault = ['input74'=>'', 'input75'=>'',...]
```

Then `array_merge` this with your post array, and it will fill in all the missing values. NOTE: Order is important [check out the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

Use `array_merge($aryDefault, $_POST)` so that `$_POST` overwrites the defaults.

Also, you can use variable variables so you can do this in a loop. If all your variable are named after your array keys, like in your example.

Full Code:

```
$aryDefault = ['input74'=>'', 'input75'=>'',...];
$aryFinal = array_merge($aryDefaults, $_POST);
foreach( $aryFinal as $key=>$value){
  $$key = $value;
}
```

You could even generate $aryDefault with a loop, if its super big.

```
$aryDefault = array();
for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
  $aryDefault["input$i"] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly seeing that you want to set a variable to post or otherwise default value you can do it following the below structure:

```
$variable = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name] : "defaultvalue";
```

That will set the variable of it exists otherwise set the default value specified. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function to encapsulate the code before PHP 7:

```
function post($key, $default = null){
    return isset ($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:$default;
}
```

Since PHP 7 (using the [null coalescing operator (`??`)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)):

```
function post($key, $default = null){
    return $_POST[$key] ?? $default;
}
```

or better whithout function just simple (as mentioned above)

```
$value74 = $_POST['input74'] ?? ''; #default value
$value75 = $_POST['input75'] ?? ''; #default value
$value76 = $_POST['input76'] ?? ''; #default value
```